# PowerShell Substring Exception

Tags: powershell, substring

I'm trying to use Substring() function in PowerShell. This is the example :

```
$string = "example string"

$temp = $string.Substring(5,($string.Length))
```

In this example I'm trying to get part of `$string`, from the `5th char`, until the end. I'm using the `.Length` property to get the last index of `$string`.

The problem is that I'm getting this exception :
`Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s)` because of `.Length` property.

What can I do to get part of `$string` until the last char?

Answer (score 2):

`$string.Length` indicates you want a substring that is as long as `$string`, which is not possible if you are starting at the 5th character of `$string`. [[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)]

Specify `$string.Length - 5` or - much simpler - omit the 2nd argument

```
$string = "example string"

$temp = $string.Substring(5,($string.Length - 5))
$temp = $string.Substring(5)                       # much simpler
```

[This Tip of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx) helps to get to grips with PowerShell string manipulation.

Comment: I thought that Substring is like(Starting Index,Ending Index). never thought about like you presented it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkedOne Np! I've edited to add links to .NET documentation and TechNet tip.

Comment: Furthermore, strings in PowerShell are zero-origin, so even if you had a substring function that took a startindex and an endindex, you wouldn't want to use `$stringname.length`, as that would be indexing one character beyond the end of the actual string.